# In Emacs is it possible to clone a *grep* or *compile* buffer and retain the search/select capability?

Tags: emacs, compiler-errors, grep

I do a lot of searching through hostile code-bases with grep and find in emacs.

I'd like to be able to stash the results of a grep including its context (ie base directory) and the results hyperlinks into the files, such that I can fire off a bunch of other grep calls, but still return to the earlier set of results if those results turned up nothing.

A similar feature for the `*compile*` buffer would be helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to clone the buffer. Just rename the `*grep*` buffer with `M-x rename-buffer`. Then the next time you do a `grep` it will create a new `*grep*` buffer.

Comment: I'm never creative enough to think of meaningful new buffer names :-p  - so I'll stick with clone myself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, while trying to work out how to ask the question I accidentally found the answer.

```
M-x clone-buffer
```

will duplicate the `*grep*` buffer into `*grep*<n>` with all of its properties intact, and future greps will go back to the normal `*grep*` buffer, thus leaving your new clone intact.